# domdocument removeChild inconsistent results

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

domdocument isn't very well documented anywhere(including SO), so I thought I would ask the question here.  I have a PHP/XML blog and want to give the blogger the ability to delete multiple blog post at one time.  The following code works when two post ids are out of order or don't follow each other.

example - when post id 1 and post id 4 are selected, they both delete.  But when post 1 and post 2 are selected, only 2 is deleted.  The behavior is consistent every time.  Has anybody come across this before, or see something in my code that would cause this?

pseudo XML:
    
`<root>`
       `<blog id=1><copy>Some copy</copy></blog>`
       `<blog id=2><copy>Another block of copy</copy></blog>`
       `<blog id=3><copy>Last chance copy</copy></blog>`
    `</root>`

PHP code to delete blog post (fragment of larger class):

```
     /**
     * method usage: $objVar->deletePost($param)
     * delete client selected xml[blog] entries
     * @param array, $params : assign $_POST array as argument
     * @return string, XML
     */
    public function deletePost($params) {

    foreach ($params as $value){ // assign $param['delete[n]'] to array
        $pid=$value;   // array[n][id]
    }

    $xml = new DOMDocument(); // instance of current xml
    $xml->load($this->fp);    // path to file
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    //define xpath object, called with query() line 273
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

    //create temporary DOM xml
    $tempxml = $xml->documentElement;

    $pnode = $xml->getElementsByTagName('blog');
     foreach($pnode as $key){       //outter loop thru parent nodes
      foreach($pid as $v){          //inner loop thru pid array
      if ($key->getAttribute('id')==$v){    //if pid matches blog[id=n]
        $path = "//root/blog[@id=".$v."]";
        $nodelist = $xpath->query($path);
        $removenode = $nodelist->item(0);

        //remove the parent/children for matching ids
        $oldxml = $tempxml->removeChild($removenode);
      }
     }
    }
    echo $xml->saveXML();

  }
```

As always, thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly do you pass as `$params`? In the above code, you overwrite `$pid` multiple times until it holds the last item of `$params`.

Comment: $params holds the blog ids (in $_POST[delete][$i] array) which was a checkbox selection made by user.  However, once $params is assigned to the pid array, I'm done with that.  Its pid that get iterated over.

Comment: `foreach ($params as $value){ $pid=$value; }` should be `[]=` instead of `=` then, or directly `$pid = $params` instead of the loop.

Comment: Let me give that a try. Thanks